# How can I use the same properties on different classes?

Tags: c#, class, properties, get, set

```
public class Data
{   public Area Area { get; set; }
    public Dimensions Dimensions { get; set; } 
}
public class Dimensions
{
    public Length Length { get; set; }
    public Width Width { get; set; }
    public Height Height { get; set; }
}
public class Height
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class Length
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
public class Width
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

this is the Model i have, how can i make this more generic to reduce the number of lines for Height, Width, Length so that the **Value** property is common on all the classes. Thank you in advance

Comment: Why are Height, Length, and Width classes instead of primitive values?  Why are they each *different* classes instead of one class used three times?  The reason(s) behind that is likely to influence any refactoring you do at this point.

Comment: this is the model that is created based on json data. so im trying to keep it clean and refractor

Comment: How about a single `Dimension` class with a `Value` property? Then use that as the type of `Length`, `Width` and `Height`?

Comment: Might help seeing the json that forces that model.

Comment: but it can be done with using simple logic ... 1) I got 3 classes `Height`, `Length`, `Width` - they look the same - what happend if I use on , fx `Length` instead all of them ... 2) well, it compiles and working ... but name of class is inappropriate ... 3) ok I can rename it ... lets call it `Dimension` ... **job done**

Answer (score 0):

You could make it generic.

```cs
public class Data
{   public Area Area { get; set; }
    public Dimensions Dimensions { get; set; } 
}

public class Dimensions
{
    public DimensionsValue<int> Length { get; set; }
    public DimensionsValue<int> Width { get; set; }
    public DimensionsValue<int> Height { get; set; }
}

public class DimensionsValue<T>
{
    public T Value {get; set;}
}
```

This way you can use `long`, `double` or any other type you want.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why are you trying to do that but I recommend you to have a syntax like below

```
public class Data
{   
    public Area Area { get; set; }
    public Dimensions Dimensions { get; set; } 
}
public class Dimensions
{
    public Length Length { get; set; }
    public Width Width { get; set; }
    public Height Height { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseValue<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}


public class Height : BaseValue<int>
{
}
public class Length : BaseValue<int>
{
}
public class Width : BaseValue<int>
{
}
```